# Using gulp-angular-templatecache in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, gulp, angular-templatecache

I followed this tutorial:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache

I do not know where to put this in my project.
in this point..

```
angular.module("templates").run([$templateCache,
 function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template1.html",
   // template1.html content (escaped) 
  );
  $templateCache.put("template2.html",
   // template2.html content (escaped) 
  );
  // etc. 
 }
]);
```

as syntax, I'm not sure which part should go, I'm trying to follow this tutorial judiciously

this is my file app.js

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ionic', 'myapp.controllers', 'myapp.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
.
.
```

I have a question, doing this all my templates were modified? because this is what I need. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this post is what you lookin for, i did it for one of my project.

[Gulp Deploy](https://medium.com/istarter-io/gulp-ionic-for-deploy-b51f52e99af#.ai7djagvs)